# MySQL stored procedure looping control

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am looping over a cursor and have the standard exist loop control set however in the loop I also do select into from another table, if this search returns no results then that triggers the exit handler and the loop terminates.

My question is: How do I attached the continue handler for the loop to a cursor and ignore the select into or how do I get round this problem?

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_results=1;
.
.   
.
search_loop:WHILE (no_more_results=0) DO
.
 FETCH my_csr INTO something;
.
    SELECT thing INTO my_thing FROM `dups` where `dups`.thing = thing_id;
```

The last select triggers the exit conditions...

Thanks 
Paul

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the documentation for the continue handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is expecting zero or one rows, use the `SET` syntax:

```
SET my_thing = (SELECT thing FROM dups where dups.thing = thing_id);
```

This will set `my_thing` to `null` if there are no rows.

I haven't tested this, so if it is *still* setting the handler, change to this, which always returns a row:

```
SET my_thing = SELECT IFNULL((SELECT thing FROM dups where dups.thing = thing_id), null);
```

Alternatively, you can convert your statement similarly:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT thing FROM dups where dups.thing = thing_id), null) INTO my_thing;
```

I believe these alternatives are presented in order of readability.

Comment: Thanks for that, the first example worked. So the "select into" statement just returns the same error code for "not found" as the FETCH on the cursor?

Comment: Yes - it's a shorthand version for an on-the-fly cursor that receives at most one row. Beware conditions that could return *multiple* rows. Consider using `select max(thing) ...` to ensure maximum one row.